# Expose only a subset of .NET OData APIs for a route (return 404 for excluded APIs)

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, odata, asp.net-web-api-routing

**Background/Context:**

We have two routes, with different route prefixes:

1. Route 1 prefix: `/api`
2. Route 2 prefix: `/api/partial`

Currently, we use the same EdmModel for both route prefixes. (See the first code snippit, named "What we currently do").

**What we want:**

We need to only allow a subset of API functionality for Route 2: `/api/partial`. We want to return `404` when someone tries to access an API that is not available to the "partial" EdmModel

Example:

1. We want to return `404` for `/api/parial/products`, where `products` is not defined in this "partial" API route.
2. We want to still route `/api/products` to the controller method

**What we've tried:**

Using a second EdmModel, that contains only a subset of the entities available in the full EdmModel. (See the second code snippit, named "What we want to do:".)

**Problem:**

We get an error on service startup:
`The path template 'products' on the action 'Export' in controller 'Products' is not a valid OData path template. Resource not found for the segment 'products'.)`

*My best guess at what is happening is that the .NET OData library scans all of the OData controllers, functions, actions and expect each of them to be explicitly defined in the EdmModel for each route. If this is true, then this solution (initializing a new EdmModel) will likely not work...*

**Is this not supported? If not, what other options are there to accomplish this? Must we explicitly return 404 in the controller API function? This would require analyzing the path for "api/subset" in the API function, which seems to me like a hack.**

**What we currently do:**

```
private static IEdmModel GetFullEdmModel()
{
    var builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();

    var orders = builder.EntitySet<Order>("orders");
    orders.EntityType.HasKey(o => o.Id);
    orders.EntityType.Property(o => o.Id).Name = "id";

    var products = builder.EntitySet<Product>("products");
    products.EntityType.HasKey(p => p.Id);
    products.EntityType.Property(p => p.Id).Name = "id";
    products.EntityType.Action("Export").Returns<ExportResponse>();

    return builder.GetEdmModel();
}

protected override void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{
    base.Register(config);

    var model = GetFullEdmModel();
    var conventions = ODataRoutingConventions.CreateDefaultWithAttributeRouting(config, model);

    // Map route 1 to {model}
    config.MapODataServiceRoute(
        routeName: "route1",
        routePrefix: "/api",
        model: model, 
        pathHandler: new CustomBIODataPathHandler(), 
        routingConventions: conventions);

    // Map route 2 to {model}
    config.MapODataServiceRoute(
        routeName: "route2",
        routePrefix: "/api/partial", // different route prefix
        model: model, // but it uses the same model
        pathHandler: new CustomBIODataPathHandler(), 
        routingConventions: conventions);
}
```

**What we want to do:**

```
private static IEdmModel GetPartialEdmModel()
{
    var builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();

    // Include only one entity
    var orders = builder.EntitySet<Order>("orders");
    orders.EntityType.HasKey(o => o.Id);
    orders.EntityType.Property(o => o.Id).Name = "id";

    return builder.GetEdmModel();
}

protected override void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{
    base.Register(config);

    // Map route 1 to {model}
    var model = GetFullEdmModel();
    var modelConventions = ODataRoutingConventions.CreateDefaultWithAttributeRouting(config, model);
    config.MapODataServiceRoute(
        routeName: "route1",
        routePrefix: "/api",
        model: model, // use standard full model
        pathHandler: new CustomBIODataPathHandler(), 
        routingConventions: conventions);

    // Map route 2 to a new partial model: {partialModel}    
    var partialModel = GetPartialEdmModel();
    var partialModelConventions = ODataRoutingConventions.CreateDefaultWithAttributeRouting(config, model);
    config.MapODataServiceRoute(
        routeName: "route2",
        routePrefix: "/api/partial", // different route prefix
        model: partialModel, // use a sparate, partial edm model ( a subset of the full edm model )
        pathHandler: new CustomBIODataPathHandler(), 
        routingConventions: conventions);
}
```

Comment: Yikes [tightly coupling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loose_coupling) your data access to your DataAccess to your security sounds like a nightmare.  Why don't you just write one class for data access, and then expose it via two interfaces, one that has the *super* methods and one that doesn't?

Comment: @ErikPhilips This is a minified example, the actual service architecture is massive, with multiple proxy services all sharing the same terrible routing conventions. This is what I'm dealing with and unfortunately do not have the ability to re-architect the entire service.

Comment: Simply using the [Adapter Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern).

Comment: @ErikPhilips Thank you for the tip but could you provide a little more clarity on your suggestion? Are you suggesting applying the adapter pattern to the EdmModel in some way?

Comment: Why not just adding `[ODataRoute({products})] Get(FromODataUri] String products) { return NotFound(); }` from partial controller?

Comment: @JamesWierzba did you ever solve your issue? I'm looking to do something similar as you.

Answer (score 1):

You need two different models or a more `intelligent` model with conditions as entitiy `products` is not available in all paths but only in `/api/products`.
In general the Error-message is explaining it already quite well but perhaps you just need it in other words.

I think the cleaner way is to provide an own model for each route, then it's quite easy to add or remove whatever you need inside.
If you mix everything in one model it will always be under construction if a new route is added or changed.

```
// Map route 1 to {model}
config.MapODataServiceRoute(
    routeName: "route1",
    routePrefix: "/api",
    model: GetApiModel(), 
    pathHandler: new CustomBIODataPathHandler(), 
    routingConventions: conventions);


// Map route 2 to {model}
config.MapODataServiceRoute(
    routeName: "route2",
    routePrefix: "/api/partial", // different route prefix
    model: GetApiPartialModel(),
    pathHandler: new CustomBIODataPathHandler(), 
    routingConventions: conventions);
```

It's a concept and I'm not so firm with the notation in that code so you might have to adjust it a bit.

Alternatively, if you really want to use only one model just try it like this:

```
// Map route 1 to {model}
config.MapODataServiceRoute(
    routeName: "route1",
    routePrefix: "/api",
    model: GetFullEdmModel("/api"), 
    pathHandler: new CustomBIODataPathHandler(), 
    routingConventions: conventions);

// Map route 2 to {model}
config.MapODataServiceRoute(
    routeName: "route2",
    routePrefix: "/api/partial", // different route prefix
    model: GetFullEdmModel("/api/partial"), // but it uses the same model
    pathHandler: new CustomBIODataPathHandler(), 
    routingConventions: conventions);
```

Then you can use the parameter to implement any conditions or a switch.

Beside that you've probably faults in your desired code in the bottom:

```
// Map route 1 to {model}
var model = GetFullEdmModel();
var modelConventions = ODataRoutingConventions.CreateDefaultWithAttributeRouting(config, model);
config.MapODataServiceRoute(
    routeName: "route1",
    routePrefix: "/api",
    model: model, // use standard full model
    pathHandler: new CustomBIODataPathHandler(), 
    routingConventions: modelConventions);
```

See the last line, that has to be adjusted for both blocks then.
I never took care before about the two lines above each config-block, so primary the problem is probably that not all variables are fitting together and you've to check it in all details.

Comment: David, this is exactly what I'm looking to do: define this `intelligent model`, with a `condition` that can specify an API is not available (However, I would highly prefer to whitelist API functions, instead of blacklist them. If you can provide a proof of concept of this, I will accept this answer

Comment: @JamesWierzba updated, hope it's working somehow like that.

Comment: @JamesWierzba again

Comment: David, how is this any different than the solution that I've tried? I tried this exactly (the first code sample), and Web API OData library does not support this. It crashes with an error on startup, because it appears to expect every API method in the service (i.e. everything with an `[OData ...]` attribute) to be mapped to every model.

Comment: @JamesWierzba sorry perhaps my last addition is helping. I've no environment like that so I can't test anything.